# Access IBM Db2 from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: db2, visual-studio-2022

I'm looking for some tooling to manage Db2 from within the Visual Studio 2022 IDE but I'm having no luck.

It seems that there is a package called "IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio" available from IBM, but the download page has a broken link.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=started-installing-add-ins-visual-studio

Can anyone recommend an alternate link where I can download this tool or any other?
Does anyone have advice about managing Db2 from Windows? Which tools should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: There are buttons on the documentation page to provide feedback, e.g., to notify about broken links. I just did that for the page you referenced.

You should be able to download the Visual Studio Add-ins from this [IBM Db2 download page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-initial-version-115-clients-and-drivers).

In case you are using Visual Studio Code, then you could use Db2-related [extensions provided by IBM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/IBM). They are different to those in Visual Studio.